# Windows PC users watch videos over LAN without Copy possibility

Tags: windows, video, lan, streaming, video-streaming

Is there any idea to make videos playable on Windows PCs over LAN, so the users can not copy the played files.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can read the file you can copy the file.  There isn't a operating system that exists that has been able to solve the problem you describe.

Comment: the idea is to make or use an interface to let the user play the file only, with many limitations.

Comment: So write a custom application to play the video.  But if the user knows the filename they can find the file and copy it.

Comment: so using an application such as Process Monitor will reveal the file name ? what is the method to broadcast or stream the file only over LAN?

Comment: @op, how are you imagining that the user says "I want to watch this video"? Anyway, this is an immensely complicated request, and we can't point you to a single app or resource that will cover everything you need to understand to implement your system. that and drm is distasteful, so I won't dirty my hands with it further.

Comment: There are several ways to stream a file over a lan connection.  Yes;  I can guarantee you that any method you attempt or try I could locate the file.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows can do that with Windows Media Sharing service (im not sure about english name of that service). It's Windows Media Player feature, not windows itself. If WMP is considered as Windows OS part - such operating system exists and it is called Windows ;)

Comment: @Kamil - How am I wrong exactly?  I said there was several ways.  **But I can still determine which file your sharing**

Comment: @Ramhound I dont think so. I think user on other side cant see physical file no matter what. Even if he could - he will not have permissions to read that file. WMPNetworkSvc service reads that file and makes stream from it. That service runs on LOCAL_SERVICE account in system and file is read by LOCAL_SERVICE.

Comment: @Kamil - By sharing a file the permission has to allow the device or user to read the file. I guarantee you I could figure out which file was being shared.

Comment: @Ramhound The point is that Media Sharing in Windows/WMP is not based on sharing files. It exposes streaming service in local network.

Comment: @Kamil - Actually it does. **Your own link in your answer even states that.** You have to enable file sharing to allow media to be shared to other devices on the network.

Comment: @Ramhound File sharing service is necessary for Media Sharing for just one reason - to broadcast that media server exists over windows network neigbourhood. Or whatever it is called in english. Files from your shared media library are NOT EXPOSED (unless you share them manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Media Player offers such feature when you share movies as media, not as files. It works like streaming server. You need WMP11 or newer.

[Share your media in Windows Media Player with other people or devices](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows-vista/share-your-media-in-windows-media-player-with-other-people-or-devices)

It will not allow to copy your music and videos normal way,

however... video still can be recorded by using CamStudio, Fraps and other screen recording software.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by Installing and Configuring a RTMP Streaming Server to broadcast the Videos, however you will most probably need Gigabit Network Link. But someone can still Capture the Broadcast into a file.